# How to get record by object id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, meanjs

I want to get record based on student id and i follwed the following method,but i use to get empty even the data exists.
my data in db,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58526f02b7258b0ec168ee77"),
"student" : ObjectId("58525c4c8cdabb7841b68163"),
"updated" : null,
"record_type" : "Invoice",
"created" : ISODate("2016-12-15T10:22:58.801Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

}

my query,

```
  exports.searchInvoiceByStudent = function (req, res) {
  var data = {},
  id = req.params.id,
  item = {'record_type':'Invoice','student':id};
  Invoice.find(item).exec(function (err, invoice) {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
  if (invoice.length > 0) {
    data = { status: 'success', error_code: 0, data: invoice };
  } else {
    data = { status: 'fail', error_code: 1, data: invoice };
  }
  res.jsonp({ 'details': invoice });
  });
};
```

But i am getting an empty array,can any one please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the schema definition for `Invoice`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
 exports.searchInvoiceByStudent = function (req, res) {
  var data = {},
  id = req.params.id,
  item = {'record_type':'Invoice','student':id};
  Invoice.find({student : id, record_type: 'Invoice}, function (err, invoice) {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
  if (invoice.length > 0) {
    data = { status: 'success', error_code: 0, data: invoice };
  } else {
    data = { status: 'fail', error_code: 1, data: invoice };
  }
  res.jsonp({ 'details': invoice });
  });
```

This version uses a direct callback (instead of the exec).

Or if you like the promise (the promise is returned by `exec`), you must add your query- result- listener using `Promise#addBack(listener)`, which is missing in your code example.

The mongoose docs mention this example (for the promise- case):

```
// using the promise returned from executing a query
var query = MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 });
var promise = query.exec();
promise.addBack(function (err, docs) {});
```